# Mailchimp sign up PopUp does not work

Tags: mailchimp

I am trying to implement a signup PopUp from Mailchimp but as it seems, I am not able to make it working! Here's the code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script><script type="text/javascript">require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"http://mc.us9.list-manage.com","uuid":"146962178e8704d5ccaf9c28f","lid":"e13cc10d95"}) })    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <p>This is a test!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

If I open the html file (locally), it loads but nothing else happen. Also there is no html code embedded what I would expect it to do. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you have to know a couple of things:

1. this shows your popup on page load (hence no HTML code)
2. it only shows once since it places a cookie, and if you already saw your popup won't bother you with it again. (try it in private mode in your browser)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add in header this google libraly `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`